# Anyone know how to do a LAG regression using R?

Tags: regression

Can someone show me how to do a basic time lag correlation in R ?
Where it tries out all combinations of lags, and finds the best one.
The best one clear meaning the one with the highest correlation coefficient.

What commands do I use?

Here is a sample data where the "solution" is that you are very happy exactly 3 hours after your fitness.

Workout hour 6, and happiness spikes in hour 9
Workout hour 15, and happiness spikes in hour 18

```
Hour,Fitness,Happiness
0,0,5
1,0,5
2,0,5
3,0,5
4,0,5
5,0,6
6,1,4
7,0,5
8,0,5
9,0,9
10,0,4
11,0,5
12,0,4
13,0,5
14,0,4
15,1,4
16,0,5
17,0,6
18,0,9
19,0,4
20,0,4
21,0,5
22,0,5
23,0,4
24,0,4
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Generally, this is not the way that one would do a time series analysis. You don't generally just throw a whole bunch of lagged variables in a regression and see which one has the largest correlation coefficient.

Time series data exhibits correlations among data points which are close together in time, violating the i.i.d. assumption of a multiple linear regression. This will be the case even if you regress on some $X_{t-i}$ term (for some arbitrary $i$ and thereby remove its variance from the error term) because correlations in time between the other variables will still remain.

[This](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/lag.html) function can be used to create lagged variables and you could write a for loop to generate an arbitrary number of lags, before putting them all in a linear model and using the one that has the smallest p value. However be advised that this will generate inaccurate statistics and is not recommended.

The more rational approach is to use the a package like `dynlm`, `auto.arima` or similar to create a dynamic linear model and have a look at [this](http://robjhyndman.com/research/Rtimeseries_handout.pdf) link for instructions on  which commands to use (and a general idea of the modelling workflow for time series models.) `Auto.arima` as described in that link is probably the closest to the function you need I suspect.

Comment: Ok, I'll look into this